# How to pass the file name dynamically to awk when awk is used in command substitution to build the shell array?

Tags: unix

Here is the script I am using and this is working fine

```
# This is a test file which we are creating and this will be used to create the shell array
cat > test.txt <<End-of-message
1A|1B|1C|1D
2A|2B|2C|2D
3A|3B|3C|3D
4A|4B|4C|4D
End-of-message

set -A col1_arr `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" }{print $1}' test.txt`

i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#col1_arr[@]} ]
do
    echo "Column 1 is:${col1_arr[$i]}"
    (( i=i+1 ))
done

rm test.txt # delet the test file
```

I do not want to hard-code test.txt and want to be able to pass it as a variable. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
set -A col1_arr `awk -v file=$myfile -F '|' \
    'END { while (getline < file) print $1 }' /dev/null`
```

`awk` will advance to a new record only when the main input stream has a new record.  So you have to do the loop manually in an `END` block, and make sure the awk script reaches the end block by specifying /dev/null as the main input stream.

Comment: I got a downvote. Downvoter, please add a comment to tell me what you find incorrect about this answer. Perhaps I can improve it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are trying to produce the following output:

```
Column 1 is: 1A
Column 1 is: 2A
Column 1 is: 3A
Column 1 is: 4A
```

If that is the case, we don't need that long and complicated series of commands. This will do:

```
awk -F'|' '{print "Column 1 is: " $1}' test.txt
```

If you still want to use a variable instead of file name, then set it (example in Bash):

```
fileName=test.txt
awk -F'|' '{print "Column 1 is: " $1}' $fileName
```

Answer (score -1):

We can pass the file name dynamically to awk regardless of awk being used in command substitution, e. g., if the file name is the script's first argument:

```
... `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" }{print $1}' $1`
```